# Codeigniter redirect() issue with $_session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I generate random number in the `post_ads()` method then store it in `$_SESSION['temp_id']` , just simple calling the `post_as_offline()` method using `redirect('ads/post_as_offline', 'refresh' )` , the `$_SESSION['temp_id']` changed and replaced by new random number. Why after redirect , `rand()` called and regenerate and store new value ?

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class ads extends CI_Controller {
    private $Data;
    public function post_ads()
    {
     $this->common_data();
     $rand = rand(); 
     $_SESSION['temp_id'] = $rand ; // example $_SESSION['temp_id'] = 1000 ; 
     if(iSset($_POST['add']))
        {
        // some code  
         redirect('ads/post_as_offline' , 'refresh');
        }
       else
       {
       $this->load->view('add_ads_step2' , $this->Data);
       }

    }
    public function post_as_offline()
    {   
       $this->common_data();
       // will be $_SESSION['temp_id'] = 52635 ; rand() regenerat value after redirect 
       $this->load->view('post_as_offline_step',$this->Data);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your session get change after post action. try this:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class ads extends CI_Controller {
    private $Data;
    public function post_ads()
    {
     $this->common_data();
        if(iSset($_POST['add']))
        {
        // some code  
         redirect('ads/post_as_offline' , 'refresh');
        }
       else
       {
        $rand = rand(); 
        $_SESSION['temp_id'] = $rand ; // example $_SESSION['temp_id'] = 1000 ; 

        $this->load->view('add_ads_step2' , $this->Data);
       }

    }
    public function post_as_offline()
    {   
       $this->common_data();
       // will be $_SESSION['temp_id'] = 52635 ; rand() regenerat value after redirect 
       $this->load->view('post_as_offline_step',$this->Data);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I checked random on before and after redirect are same .you can check easily by getting into url that session value .I checked Your code on my test page by just only removing common data method. Please check if something you missed into your posted question .
Example :-

```
private $Data;
public function post_ads()
    {
        $rand = rand();
        $_SESSION['temp_id'] = $rand ; // example $_SESSION['temp_id'] = 1000 ;
        if(isset($_SESSION))
        {
            redirect('test/post_as_offline?code='.$_SESSION['temp_id'] , 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('add_ads_step2' , $this->Data);
        }

    }
    public function post_as_offline()
    {
        print_r($_SESSION);die;
        $this->load->view('post_as_offline_step',$this->Data);
    }
```